# PHP GET variable array injection

Tags: php, security, arrays, get, exploit

I've recently learned that it's possible to inject arrays into PHP GET variables to perform code execution?

`.php?a[]=asd&a[]=asdasd&b[]=$a`

That was the example I was given. I have no idea how it works and was wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Samsung. Let me be the first to award you 12 reputation points ;)

Answer (score 9):

PHP will parse the query string, and inject those values in the `$_GET` super-global array *(same for `$_POST` if this was done in a form using POST, btw)*.

In your case, the `$_GET` array will contain this :

```
array
  'a' => 
    array
      0 => string 'asd' (length=3)
      1 => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
  'b' => 
    array
      0 => string '$a' (length=2)
```

Each value passed in the query string will be put by PHP in the `$_GET` array, creating sub-arrays if necessary, when there are `[]` used in the query string.

But this doesn't cause any kind of "code execution" : as long as you deal with input properly *(i.e. don't trust the input and use `eval` on it, or any kind of bad idea like this)*, there is no risk of code-injection.

Comment: Thanks for providing a thorough response for the asker, Pascal. It creates a much better environment around here.

Comment: @Jonathan : Thanks :-) ;; just trying to help ; hope it does ^^ ; I suppose it's kind of my way of "giving back"

Answer (score 7):

If you are not sure how to get secure, the least you can do is to filter the $_GET array. Here is the function:

```
function filter_url($url)
{
  if (is_array($url))
  {
    foreach ($url as $key => $value)
    {
      // recurssion
      $url[$key] = filter_url($value);
    }
    return $url;
  }
  else
  {
    // remove everything except for a-zA-Z0-9_.-&=
    $url = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-&=]/', '', $url);
    return $url;
  }
}
```

Now you can filter the $_GET like this:

```
$_GET = filter_url($_GET);
```

This will essentially clean up your $_GET array from suspicious characters such as [ ].

Thanks

Comment: It was perfect and solved my issue...Thank you.
 If you want to know, I was having injections on my website and using "mysqli_real_escape", was blocking injections, but also was preventing the website functions to wokr ... but now, function is working and injection is blocked. THANK YOU

Comment: Great, simple solution. There is an error in the regex, the a-Z should be a-z otherwise php gives errrors :)

Comment: @Spaceship09 Nice finding, but can you tell me how can I add spaces too?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $_GET['a'][0]; //prints "asd"
echo $_GET['a'][1]; //prints "asdasd"
echo $_GET['b'][0]; //prints "$a"
```

Answer (score 2):

The above does not strictly allow code execution, but it may alter the control flow of your existing code if it does not take into account the fact the data may be an array.

The reason the above works is because PHP interprets variables ending in [] as arrays. So if you provide multiple GET variables with same name ending in [], PHP creates an array containing all the values.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: no code execution. Otherwise, don't you think somebody would have hacked Facebook already? :)

I think the person who told you that was confused about some other bugs that used deep array nesting to trigger a buffer overflow/double free/some other hack vector, that could theorically be used to execute some code. Those are software bugs as you can see everyday in many popular software. They usually get patched quickly.

You might find more info at http://www.suspekt.org/

Answer (score 2):

I think he is talking about something evaluating differently when passed an array

`strcasecmp( $_GET['password'], $password ) == 0 )`
`{`
`echo($secret);`
`}`
`
If you pass an empty array into strcasecmp it will evaluate to true for whatever reason.

IE: index.php?password=[]

Comment: +1 this is also documented here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Input_handling

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you misunderstood something.

The above example simply creates an array like

```
Array (
  [a] => Array (
    [0] => asd
    [1] => asdasd
  )
  [b] => Array ( [0] => $a )
)
```

This is documented and works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Someone lied to you, you won't execute anything with that, you'll just send an array instead of a plain variable.

try this code

```
<?php
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    var_dump($x);
?>
```

and access it using ?x=1 and then ?x[a]=1&x[b]=2 it's expected behavior, not injection and you can't run any code with it.

Answer (score 0):

your url want to be like that

www.mysite.com/page.php?**name=john**

but you want to prevent insert something like this

www.mysite.com/page.php?**name[]=john**

solution:

```
<?php
 $myname = is_array($_GET['name'])? "invalid" : $_GET['name'] ;
 echo $myname;
?>
```