# PHP 403 Error when uri have "[]"

Tags: php

I creat server and install apache & php (Centos 64bit 6.x)
i will creat file test.js.php

```
// Send correct type
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
// Enable browser cache for 1 hour
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 3600) . ' GMT');

if (! empty($_GET['scripts']) && is_array($_GET['scripts'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['scripts'] as $script) {
        // Sanitise filename
        $script_name = 'js';

        $path = explode("/", $script);
        foreach ($path as $index => $filename) {
            // Allow alphanumeric, "." and "-" chars only, no files starting
            // with .
            if (preg_match("@^[\w][\w\.-]+$@", $filename)) {
                $script_name .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
            }
        }

        // Output file contents
        if (preg_match("@\.js$@", $script_name) && is_readable($script_name)) {
            readfile($script_name);
            echo ";\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And i will access this file with url `http://124.x.x.x/js/test.js.php?scripts[]=jquery1.11.js`
and server response error 403 Forbidden

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /js/test.js.php on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at xxxx.org Port 80
```

When i change `scripts[]` to `scripts` then working fine, but i want to know why my server response 403 if using `scripts[]` on URI?

Any ideal?

Comment: what are you trying to do,`script[]` wont work

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738 specificlly section 2.2

Comment: @FerozAkbar how can to fix this? Can do this work?

Comment: why are you using [] at all? `scripts=` makes sense. `scripts[]=` does not

Comment: @Dagon i will install PHPMyadmin in my server, and they have a file get scripts likes this but don't work `phpMyAdmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?token=482ce42ba410ac9d84d8dd716dac83c7&scripts[]=jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js`

Comment: @Dagon The brackets make the data an array, needed for PHP. e.g. `?foo[]=1&foo[]=2`

Comment: $_GET **is** an array

Comment: @Dagon it makes `$_GET['scripts']` an array.

Comment: This is a bit weird and since it's an apache error I don't think it has anything to do with your PHP code. Can you post your `.htaccess` file? Do you get the same error adding arbitrary GET data like `doesntexist.php?test[]=1`?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks for your idea, my folder don't have .htaccess but my root folder have htaccess file, and this file make my code don't work. Voted for you

Answer (score 1):

You must have `mod_security` enabled. `mod_seciruty` is a WAF (Web Application Firewall) module to prevent your server from cyber attacks.

"[]" in url can be used to exploit variable injection vulerabilities, so the WAF block your request to protect server. This error is raised from Apache.

Check out this similar thread:

[GET with hyphens raises error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329657/get-with-hyphens-raises-error-403/14330416#14330416)

Disabling mod_security will instantly solve the issue, but it's really a terrible idea.

**Try avoid using "[]".** You can still implement the feature without it:

```
$scripts = explode($_GET['scripts'], ',');
```

Comment: Can you link to any reference for this, as far as `?key[]` being blocked? It's not always possible to avoid brackets in keys in a clean way.

Comment: @WesleyMurch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885979/php-get-variable-array-injection

Comment: I mean any reference to what `mod_security` actually blocks? I couldn't find it via Google. I'm pretty sure this is the right answer but I was just curious.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Sorry I'm unable to access StackOverflow recently, due to  internet censorship of the Firewall you know. (Damn it!) `mod_secrity` filters harmful content from HTTP requests, including $_COOKIE, $_POST, $_GET. AFAIN, its rules are based on RegExp. You can check the log file to see which rule was fired during your request.